# When will we see Store Apps enabled in Windows Sandbox?

Tags: hyper-v, modern-ui, windows-store-app, windows-store, windows-sandbox

Windows Sandbox is incredibly useful to me; having an instant Container that I use to try things out is great, it's an amazing feature, but I just can't get my head around why Store Apps do not work here. I'm wanting to know if anyone here has *reasons* why this might be:

- If every Virtual Machine can support Store Apps, why can Windows Sandbox not do so (i.e. does anyone have *specific* technical reasons why they do not work; less interested in speculation, I'm more wondering if people have specific knowledge on this from Microsoft)?
- Are there currently any plans for Store Apps to be included in a future Windows Sandbox release (again, I'm curious on specific announcements, or roadmaps that have been seen etc) and if so, when might that happen?

There has never been much documentation for Windows Sandbox; it appeared, some sparse documentation was put up on the Microsoft website and then I've heard nothing more since then. Answers to the above (or related info) would be great to know, thanks.

Comment: You need to ask Microsoft .  I am in Windows 11 Insider (so future) Sandbox and there is very little there

Comment: Isn't asking Microsoft anything like asking a palm reader to tell you your future (it's all vague odd answers from Microsoft in my experience)?  I'm hoping someone, maybe from a Microsoft conference or something like that, has some info, but yes, I don't think Sandbox changed much (if at all) in Windows 11; there could be a Sandbox update around the corner that useful stuff in it - I'm hoping someone on here might have some insight into that.

Comment: I have not seen anything like that in Sandbox

Comment: Cool, maybe someone else can give us all some insight (we can all go on the Insider channel for sure, but Microsoft often don't really give us much to go on, then drop some things all at once). I'm quite annoyed at the lack of Store App support to be honest, it's a hassle. Maybe even someone here has a hack to unlock Store App support in Sandbox, that would be really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already possible, but requires some work with PowerShell.

- [Get the URL of the app from the Microsoft Store](https://thegeekpage.com/web-url-of-a-microsoft-app/)
- Create a PowerShell script (`Download-AppxPackage.ps1`) containing
  the script from
  [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1052641/18736),
  which defines a function called `Download-AppxPackage`
- Call this function with the above URL like this:

  ```
  Download-AppxPackage "https://www.microsoft.com/p/dynamic-theme/9nblggh1zbkw" "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop"
  ```

  This may download more than one application file, so choose the
  latest version that suits your computer architecture.
- Double-click the `.Appx` or `.AppxBundle` package to install.

Comment: This is great. However, the I cannot install the one App that I really wanted this for (Microsoft Terminal) cannot be installed by this method. It's a fantastic trick, but it also begs the question that if Store Apps can work this way (and indeed, I managed to get the Calculator App to work) why have Microsoft crippled the Store in the Windows Sandbox ... I'm quite confused why they would do that.

Comment: It's a design decision by Microsoft, probably in the name of security.

Comment: When I double-click on the Appx or AppxBundle files I just get a "Select an app to open this .Appx file" dialog. Not sure what to pick here - I tried `explorer.exe` but that didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: @RichardHauer: Strange problem. You should also be able to right-click the file and select "Install".

Comment: Does this work to install the Microsoft Store itself?