# PowerShell, how to setup Microsoft Terminal and other Store Apps inside Windows Sandbox

Tags: powershell, windows-store-app, windows-store, windows-sandbox

I would like to be able to get Store Apps to work within a Windows Sandbox. I asked a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1743953/when-will-we-see-store-apps-enabled-in-windows-sandbox/1743990?noredirect=1#comment2703573_1743990) on Windows Sandbox and Store Apps in general, and @harrymc pointed me at a means to install these within Windows Sandbox (the Microsoft Store is disabled in Windows Sandbox).

I used the functions [here](https://tech.setepontos.com/2021/03/17/windows-sandbox-how-to-install-windows-store-apps/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1018220/how-do-i-install-an-app-from-windows-store-using-powershell/1052641#1052641) to download `.appx` and `.appxbundle` files for each App.

I have been able to get Calculator to work, but various others do not. In particular, I would like to get Microsoft Terminal to work inside the Windows Sandbox, and the Store App could be useful for installing other apps in the GUI.

```
Download-AppxPackage https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRFHVN5   # Calculator
Download-AppxPackage https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N0DX20HK701   # Microsoft Terminal
Download-AppxPackage https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRFJBMP   # Microsoft Store
```

After doing this, you can use `Add-AppxPackage` within Windows Sandbox against each of the files downloaded to add them into the Sandbox, and then that App should now be available in the Start Menu.

However, I have been completely unable to get Microsoft Terminal (does not download or install) or Microsoft Store (installs, but will not start) working inside a Windows Sandbox instance (Terminal was my main reason for wanting to learn if this was possible, so this is disappointing).

Can anyone get the Store App for Microsoft Terminal to function inside a Windows Sandbox using the above or other techniques, and if so, how?

Comment: Maybe you can try the other [install methods](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal#other-install-methods)

Comment: Try to download the Microsoft Terminal installation from its [microsoft / terminal project page](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).

Comment: Success. Good idea Harry. I had to mess about a bit, it wasn't clear what worked and what did not. The 2525 build did not work (error "The package requires OS version 10.0.22000.0 or higher on the Windows.Desktop device family. The device is currently running OS version 10.0.19041.2006", but the 2524 build does. I was also not sure about the prerequisite kit. Those do not seem to be required, just the "UI.Xaml" and "VCLibs" packages obtained by the Download in my question above. https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.15.2524.0

Comment: I put up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the Microsoft Terminal installation from its
[microsoft / terminal project page](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)
has worked for the poster.

His comment below the post included these details :

> I had to mess about a bit, it wasn't clear what worked and what did not. The 2525 build did not work (error "The package requires OS version 10.0.22000.0 or higher on the Windows.Desktop device family. The device is currently running OS version 10.0.19041.2006", but the 2524 build does. I was also not sure about the prerequisite kit. Those do not seem to be required, just the "UI.Xaml" and "VCLibs" packages obtained by the Download in my question above. [github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.15.2524.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.15.2524.0).

Answer (score 0):

I've found / worked out additional means to fully reinstate Windows Store (and importantly, the `WinGet` console tool) within Windows Sandbox.

Although I tried to install Windows Store manually inside Windows Sandbox, that failed due to required components being missing, but this project fills in all of the gaps:

```
git clone https://github.com/kkkgo/LTSC-Add-MicrosoftStore
```

In that folder, simply run `Add-Store.cmd` and you will now have an operational Store App on the Start Menu in Windows Sandbox, but it is not complete as a few services have to be started also:

```
# 'config start=auto' is not required on Sandbox,
# but is useful for non-Sandbox environments.
SC config wuauserv start=auto
SC config bits start=auto
SC config cryptsvc start=auto
SC config trustedinstaller start=auto
SC start wuauserv
SC start bits
SC start cryptsvc
SC start trustedinstaller
```

Windows Store and `WinGet` are now fully functional inside Windows Sandbox. You do not need to log in to the Store with a Microsoft account (but you will get a nag to do so every time you install an app). You should however, update all Store Apps. Do this by going to the "..." menu at top right and then select the "Download and Update" option (on newer Store Apps there is not "..." menu, to update Apps, do so from the "Library" button at bottom right, then "Get Updates").

The GitHub project above was built for Windows Enterprise LTSC (Long-Term Servicing Channel, designed for Windows 10 devices where the key requirement is that functionality and features don’t change over time) that, like Windows Sandbox, uses a slimmed down set of features, but this project works perfectly on Windows Sandbox. The project installs four components to achieve this:

```
Microsoft Store
Store Purchase App
App Installer
Xbox Identity Provider
```